# Got Type Int -> Int instead of Integer and don't know why

Tags: haskell, fold

I wrote this binarytodecimal-converter getting a compiler error I don't know where it's comming from.

```
binaryToInteger :: [Bool] -> Integer
binaryToInteger (x:xs) = foldr (\x y z -> (fromEnum x) * 2^y + z) 0 [0..length (x:xs)]
```

*Actually the program should give back the decimal result of a binary number.
Example given:
binaryToInteger [True, True, False] == 1*(2^2) + 1*(2^1) + 0*(2^0) == 6*

**My error message is the following:** 
Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type`Int -> Int'

```
  * Probable cause: `foldr' is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression:
    foldr (\ x y z -> (fromEnum x) * 2 ^ y + z) 0 [0 .. length (x : xs)]
  In an equation for `binaryToInteger':
      binaryToInteger (x : xs)
        = foldr
            (\ x y z -> (fromEnum x) * 2 ^ y + z) 0 [0 .. length (x : xs)]
```

Comment: You realize that `x` is only the first element of your list, and thus that you will never take the remaining elements into account?

Comment: Your fold function takes three arguments, not two. The two expected arguments are a *single* element from the list you are folding and the result of the last call to the fold function, not 2 (or more) elements from the list.

Comment: @chepner Oh thx, didn't see that!

Comment: In addition to the `foldr` issue, the reason the error mentions `Int`s is that `length`, annoyingly, is monomorphic and returns an `Int`. If you need it to be an `Integer` then either use `fromIntegral` on it, or use `genericLength` from `Data.List`.

Comment: You could have taken the time to discover for yourself, the type of `length`, and the type of `foldr`. It's a basic skill, and such information is easily accessible within `ghci`.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm goes like this:

- you start with a = 0 ("a" stands for "accumulator")
- for True: double a and add 1 to it
- for False: just double a

Example: [True, False, True]

- a = 0
- True => a becomes 1 (because 0 * 2 + 1 = 1)
- False => a becomes 2 (because 1 * 2 = 2)
- True => a becomes 5 (because 2 * 2 + 1 = 5)
- a = 5 is the solution

In Haskell code:

```hs
import Data.List (foldl')

binaryToInteger :: [Bool] -> Integer
binaryToInteger xs = foldl' f 0 xs where
    f a True  = a * 2 + 1
    f a False = a * 2
```

Don't use exponentiation (`^`), because it is bad for performance. I used a left-fold, because it is better suited for this problem. The function `foldl'` has the additional advantage that it is strict, and therefore doesn't introduce a space leak.